# Bash: How to count number of lines in a section, increment it and add another line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, count, insert

I have two files and a path variable:

path=$1

file1:

```
[usera:pathlist]
1=/path
2=/another/path

[userb:pathlist]
1=/path
2=/another/path
3=/one/more/path

[userc:pathlist]
1=/path
```

file2:

```
usera
userc
```

I need a script to add `$path` to all users in file1 if they exist in file2 and raise the linecount by one.

The result should then look like this:

file1:

```
[usera:pathlist]
1=/path
2=/another/path
3=$path

[userb:pathlist]
1=/path
2=/another/path
3=/one/more/path

[userc:pathlist]
1=/path
2=$path
```

Unfortunately i don't have enough experience with `sed` and didn't use `awk` yet. Or maybe there is another tool that suits my needs better? I would be really grateful if you could lead me into the right direction here. Thank you very much.

#### **Udpdate#1:**

```
[usera:pathlist]
1=/path
2=/another/path
1=$path

[userb:pathlist]
1=/path
2=/another/path
3=/one/more/path

[userc:pathlist]
1=/path
1=$path
```

Comment: Your expected output is not clear, so please do edit it and let us know then.

Comment: I am sorry but i am not quite sure what exactly is missing in my output? If a user does exist in file2, add the $path variable to file1 at the end of each user section and raise the linecount in that section by one.

Comment: `$path` is not clear in your output. How `3=$path` in usera is coming is not clear, kindly do add the same in your question.

Comment: My question is how to add my $path variable at the end of a usersection. I can't tell you how it's getting in usera because i don't know the solution. I need a script that will do this for me.

Comment: Do you want to add a literal `$path` or the value of the path variable?

Comment: I am sorry. I want to add the value of the path variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -v p='$path' -v ORS='\n\n' -v OFS='\n' 'NR==FNR{a["["$1]; next}
                                                     {split($1,u,":")} 
                                           u[1] in a {$(NF+1)=NF"="p}1' file2 RS= file1

[usera:pathlist]
1=/path
2=/another/path
3=$path

[userb:pathlist]
1=/path
2=/another/path
3=/one/more/path

[userc:pathlist]
1=/path
2=$path
```

to use the value of `$path` instead of the literal `$path` change single quotes with double quotes in the definition of `p` variable.  Note that `RS` value set between files.

perhaps this is simpler

```
$ awk -v p='$path' 'NR==FNR{a["["$1]; next} 
                           {split($1,u,":"); 
                            print $0 ORS (u[1] in a?NF"="p:"") ORS}' file2 RS= file1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v path="$path" '
  FNR==NR{ u[$1]; next }
  FNR > 1{ print "" }
  {
    add=0
    for (user in u) 
      if ($1 ~ "^\\[" user ":"){ add=1; break }
  }
  1
  add{ print NF "=" path }
' file2 RS="" file1
```

Comment: That almost did it! It's inserting the new line at the end but unfortunately it doesn't raise the linecount by one. See Update#1.

Comment: `$(NF-1)` should get the second to last field, i.e. `2` and increment it (`(++$(NF-1))`), it doesn't calculate the line numbers. It works with `gawk`, but not with `mawk`. What type of `awk` are you using? Let me some time to investigate, maybe I'll find a better solution.

Comment: Updated and simplified. Please try again.